# How do I replace specific substrings in kwargs keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyword-argument

I need to replace specific substrings in the key values of a dictionary. So:

```py
def some_func(name, **kwargs):
    ## Do stuff ##
    print(f"<{name}", *(f"{key}={value}" for key, value in kwargs.items()), ">")

kwargs = {'foo__':'bar', 'foo_bar':'baz'}
some_func(name='some_name', kwargs)

# Output should be:
<some_name foo=bar foo-bar=baz >
#
```

So each `key` in `kwargs` needs to be replaced by:

```py
{'foo':'bar', 'foo-bar':'baz'}
```

Which is essentially `key.replace('__', '')` and `key.replace('_', '-')`.
I've tried using dictionaries for this:

```
key_to_replace = {'__':'', '_', '-'}

print(f"<{name}", *(f"{key.replace(key, value for key, value in key_to_replace.items())}={value}" for key, value in kwargs.items()), ">")
```

But it doesn't work, it says `Generator Expression must be parenthesized`
I've tried parenthesizing `key, value for key, value in key_to_replace.items()`, but it gives out `SyntaxError`.

How do I do this?

Comment: There's some mismatched parenthesis in your code @RedFox

Comment: @Vishnudev Can you point out the place to rectify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
def some_func(name, **kwargs):
    # replace the __ and _ accordingly:
    kwargs = {
        k.replace("__", "").replace("_", "-"): v for k, v in kwargs.items()
    }
    print(f"<{name}", *(f"{key}={value}" for key, value in kwargs.items()), ">")


kwargs = {"foo__": "bar", "foo_bar": "baz"}
some_func(name="some_name", **kwargs)    # <-- put ** here
```

Prints:

```
<some_name foo=bar foo-bar=baz >
```

Comment: Oh, thanks Andrej! This works perfect. Just curious, is it also possible to add another `.replace()` to `k`?

Comment: @RedFox Yes, of course. But I'd suggest to using `re` module (`re.sub`) if you have many replacements.